# Redundant Character Escape of .(dot) in java regex

Tags: java, regex

As far as I know, `.` is a metacharacter in java regex. But when I use it as below:

```
    String s = "1.2.3.4";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\.]");
```

I got a `Redundant Character Escape` warning from IntelliJ IDEA. Any explaination?

Comment: because placing a `.` inside `[]` is enough to escape it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the square brackets. Check this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\.]");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("").find());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(".").find());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("a").find());
```

> false
>
> true
>
> false

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[.]");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("").find());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(".").find());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("a").find());
```

> false
>
> true
>
> false

If you were to use the dot outside of the square brackets your escape would be required to capture a dot rather than any character.